# Json Schema Validation failing with error in WSO2 APIM

Tags: json, wso2, apim

I am using wso2 apim 3.1.0 I want to enable json schema validation for the json payload. I have referred to the belpw document for setting up json shema validation in wso2 apim
https://m-saranki.medium.com/unboxing-json-schema-validator-320-2dd944dae6c0 . I am testing the below API for json schema validation

```
  openapi: "3.0.1"
  info: 
    title: "SampleAPI"
    version: "1.2.3"
  servers: 
    - 
      url: "/"
  security: 
    - 
      default: []
  paths: 
    /*: 
      get: 
        responses: 
          200: 
            description: "OK"
        security: 
          - 
            default: []
        x-auth-type: "Application & Application User"
        x-throttling-tier: "Unlimited"
        x-wso2-application-security: 
          security-types: 
            - "oauth2"
            - "basic_auth"
          optional: false
      put: 
        responses: 
          200: 
            description: "OK"
        security: 
          - 
            default: []
        x-auth-type: "Application & Application User"
        x-throttling-tier: "Unlimited"
        x-wso2-application-security: 
          security-types: 
            - "oauth2"
            - "basic_auth"
          optional: false
      post: 
        requestBody: 
          content: 
            application/json: 
              schema: 
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/User"
          required: false
        responses: 
          200: 
            description: "OK"
        security: 
          - 
            default: []
        x-auth-type: "Application & Application User"
        x-throttling-tier: "Unlimited"
        x-wso2-application-security: 
          security-types: 
            - "oauth2"
            - "basic_auth"
          optional: false
      delete: 
        responses: 
          200: 
            description: "OK"
        security: 
          - 
            default: []
        x-auth-type: "Application & Application User"
        x-throttling-tier: "Unlimited"
        x-wso2-application-security: 
          security-types: 
            - "oauth2"
            - "basic_auth"
          optional: false
      patch: 
        responses: 
          200: 
            description: "OK"
        security: 
          - 
            default: []
        x-auth-type: "Application & Application User"
        x-throttling-tier: "Unlimited"
        x-wso2-application-security: 
          security-types: 
            - "oauth2"
            - "basic_auth"
          optional: false
  components: 
    schemas: 
      User: 
        required: 
          - "id"
        properties: 
          id: 
            type: "string"
            format: "uuid"
          name: 
            type: "string"
          email: 
            type: "string"
            format: "email"
          dob: 
            type: "string"
            format: "date"
    securitySchemes: 
      default: 
        type: "oauth2"
        flows: 
          implicit: 
            authorizationUrl: "https://test.com"
            scopes: {}
  x-wso2-auth-header: "Authorization"
  x-wso2-cors: 
    corsConfigurationEnabled: false
    accessControlAllowOrigins: 
      - "*"
    accessControlAllowCredentials: false
    accessControlAllowHeaders: 
      - "authorization"
      - "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
      - "Content-Type"
      - "SOAPAction"
      - "apikey"
      - "Credentials"
    accessControlAllowMethods: 
      - "GET"
      - "PUT"
      - "POST"
      - "DELETE"
      - "PATCH"
      - "OPTIONS"
  x-wso2-production-endpoints: 
    urls: 
      - "http://localhost:9090/Cipango-CallAS/v1/sp/1/accounts/123/call"
    type: "http"
  x-wso2-sandbox-endpoints: 
    urls: 
      - "http://localhost:9090/Cipango-CallAS/v1/sp/1/accounts/123/call"
    type: "http"
  x-wso2-basePath: "/sample/1.2.3"
  x-wso2-transports: 
    - "http"
    - "https"
  x-wso2-response-cache: 
    enabled: false
    cacheTimeoutInSeconds: 300`
```

But when I trigger the request with correct json payload I am seeing the below error message

```
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-19 16:14:48,136]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    TID: [-1234] [] [2021-10-19 16:14:49,237] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} - Error processing POST request for : /sample/1.2.3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonArray["asBoolean"])
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3751)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3669)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.SchemaValidator.extractReference_aroundBody26(SchemaValidator.java:547)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.SchemaValidator.extractReference(SchemaValidator.java:532)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.SchemaValidator.extractSchemaFromRequest_aroundBody18(SchemaValidator.java:327)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.SchemaValidator.extractSchemaFromRequest(SchemaValidator.java:297)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.SchemaValidator.getSchemaContent_aroundBody16(SchemaValidator.java:284)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.SchemaValidator.getSchemaContent(SchemaValidator.java:281)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.SchemaValidator.validateRequest_aroundBody8(SchemaValidator.java:211)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.SchemaValidator.validateRequest(SchemaValidator.java:209)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.SchemaValidator.handleRequest_aroundBody2(SchemaValidator.java:114)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.SchemaValidator.handleRequest(SchemaValidator.java:75)
            at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:367)
            at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149)
            at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
            at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
            at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:327)
            at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:98)
            at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
            at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:368)
            at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:427)
            at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:182)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonArray["asBoolean"])
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:727)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3729)
            ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
            at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsBoolean(JsonElement.java:153)
            at com.google.gson.JsonArray.getAsBoolean(JsonArray.java:370)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
            ... 29 more
```

Let me know what could be the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Explanation**

I believe you are using wso2am-3.1.0 vanilla pack along with a custom sequence file which probably has a mediator using **"json-eval($.)"** expression. Please confirm. This is a known issue in the wso2am-3.0.0 and wso2am-3.1.0 vanilla packs.

This is becasue when we use json-eval($.) expression in a sequence in the <APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences directory and when it gets deployed, the synapse is setting the **GsonJsonProvider** [1] to represent the JSON inside the Jayway JsonPath[2].

Since the **GsonJsonProvider** is getting loaded, even if we remove the particular sequence file which has the json-eval($.) expression in a property mediator, the issue will still persists until we restart the server.

But, if we do not use the json-eval($.) expression at all in a sequence in the <APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences directory, we will not get the above error when we enable the JSON schema validation as the **jsonsmartjsonprovider** [3] is used to represent the JSON inside the Jayway JsonPath.

Since the JSON object representation is getting different in the error scenario, it throws the IllegalArgumentException in that case.

- **Solution**

You can approach one of the following solution as suggested below.

1. This issue has been fixed in the latest WUM/updated pack. If you have the WSO2 subscription then you can get the latest update.
2. You can deploy a new wso2am-3.1.0 vanilla pack and invoke the API calls without the sequence having json-eval($.) expression.

[1] https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/latest/com/jayway/jsonpath/spi/json/GsonJsonProvider.html

[2] https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/417ce10dec58579b758e12f41909f17c09d25a64/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/eip/EIPUtils.java#L348

[3] https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/latest/com/jayway/jsonpath/spi/json/JsonSmartJsonProvider.html

Comment: Thanks for replying - I do not have any mediation seq attached for the above API . But there are some other APIs which do have mediation sequence involving  json-eval($.). Does this also cause same issue as above ?

Comment: Yes. As I have explained before, when the sequences get deployed, the GsonJsonProvider will be loaded despite of the API that the sequence belongs to. This is the cause for getting this error.

Comment: what could be the alternatives to json-eval($.) for parsing json response?

Comment: To access the json payload content you can use either JSONPath expressions (with json-eval() method) or XPath expressions. Since you are facing issues with json-eval(), you can use XPath expressions. Please refer topic "Accessing content from JSON payloads" in https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/JSON+Support